# Angular frequency of discrete signal

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic

Can someone explain me how to obtain the angular frequency here?

[image]

Comment: Hi! It's impossible to know $\omega$ without knowing the sampling rate, so you're probably not showing the full exercise.

Comment: by the way, the way the exercise restricts the values of $k$ makes little sense; if a discrete sequence is periodic, it's periodic on $\mathbb Z$, not just e.g. $[-32;32]$.

Comment: furthermore, what math courses did you have? From the top of my head, the math that I had in my studies did *not* show that $\frac\pi{\sqrt2}$ is not a rational number. It's possible to show that, but, um, I don't know any easier way than showing $\pi$ is a transcendental number, and that is a proof I honestly don't understand... so, while it's right that $v_3$ is not periodic, I doubt the course you're taking actually equipped you to *know* that, much less even to *show* it!

Comment: Hello Marcus, thank you for your response. I was supposed to plot the functions in Matlab for example to v1: k1 = 0:10; v1 = (k1 == 4); stem(k1,v1);

Comment: good morning! Yeah, then, it makes more sense. So, can you answer the question what the sampling rate is?

Comment: definition of *what*? This comment makes no sense as statement of its own.

Comment: I have updated the post with the complete problem. The sampling rate is not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the problem as stated, it's impossible to derive at the $\omega$ given.

$\omega$ is the angular frequency, which is $2\pi$ times the frequency of the signal, and since it's given per second, that's impossible to derive, since you'd need the sampling rate. So, the problem is incomplete, and you couldn't have given the $\omega$!

But if you had the sampling rate $f_s$, it would be easy: The time duration $T$ of a period of length $N$ is simply $N/f_s$; therefore, the fundamental frequency of an $N$-periodic signal is $f_0=1/T=f_s/N$; and since $\omega= 2\pi f$; your $\omega=\frac{2\pi f_s}{N}$, simple as that.

Since the $\omega$ weren't asked for in the problem statement, I'd assume it's a leftover of a previous version of the question.

Comment: I think the angular frequency w is given as an extra information in the exercise. The purpose of the exercise is to analyze audio and speech signals so probably that is the sampling rate that was taken. Thank you for the clear explanation!